# Console Program results to text file

Tags: c#, console, pipeline

I have written a console program that uses TCP IP and I am now debugging in a 64 bit machine. 
The program connects ok to the server and output things in the screen (until the error I am debugging happens)
I want to record these screen outputs so I did

`>theProgram.exe > screenrecord.txt`

as a pipe. This used to work well before but for some reason now, the program when run this way although connecting to the network is now receiving just 0 bytes (by the way I could never understand what this "0 bytes" mean, I pointed out the documentation is vague at best on this)

Why this piping can be affecting the behavior of the TCP IP?
and what are methods to derive the output to a text file?

Is there a way to put these output to a text file *and* seeing them on the screen at the same time??

Comment: Can you give some more information e.g. the exception

Comment: This program is tagged as a C#,  I assume that You have created the program. Why don't You just add module for debugging into file? You can write it Yourself or use some existing (e.g.: [Log4NET](https://csharp.today/log4net-tutorial-great-library-for-logging/) ).

Comment: @Tatranskymedved thanks, could you please elaborate a little more on adding modules?

Comment: Also, could You please share information about code? Have You used any network communication library or using standard .NET? Can You show us some code? Have You done some research about this ?

Comment: @Tatranskymedved I am using standard .NET. I will post some code, but in the meantime, is there any other way to output my screen to a file? (and if possible to both file and console?)

Comment: @KansaiRobot , Check the link in the comment. After that, when You run the program, You can add parameters where the path for debug can be included, or the information if You want to debug it (string[] Args must be handled)

Comment: @KansaiRobot Try googling for a moment about I/O into files - C#. [link](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_file_io.htm) [link2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8bh11f1k.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) [link3](https://www.google.cz/search?q=C%23%20IO%20files)

Comment: @Tatranskymedved Thank you. And sorry, I think I have not made myself understood (my bad!) . I don't want to modify my code and write to a file (although if there is no other way maybe I will do) In fact, my code is already writing to a file. What I am asking is to >temporarily< shift the screen output to a text . I could do this with ">" but wonder if there is other way

Answer (score 1):

The Console can only output to 1 device at a time. The `Console.SetOut` method directs the output to another device such as your `screenrecord.txt.` As you show `>theProgram.exe > screenrecord.txt` when executed will not show any output to the screen. The same is with `Console.SetOut`, since it is redirected to a file, it won’t show up in the console. The code below was taken from MS [Console.SetOut Method (TextWriter)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.setout(v=vs.110).aspx)

Below shows one way you could redirect the console output to a file. In this code... `ScreenRecord.txt` will be saved in the debug folder of the project, or you can set a path also.

Hope this helps.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
  Console.WriteLine("Start Of Main - output not redirected yet!");
  FileStream fs = new FileStream("ScreenRecord.txt", FileMode.Create);
  // First, save the standard output.
  TextWriter tmp = Console.Out;
  StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs);
  Console.SetOut(sw);
  Console.WriteLine("this writes to file 1");
  printStuff();
  Console.SetOut(tmp);
  Console.WriteLine("this line not in file");
  Console.ReadKey();
  sw.Close();
}

private static void printStuff()
{
  for (int i = 1; i < 7; i++)
    Console.WriteLine("printStuff " + i);
}
```